# Function change data format. (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/jz3ypyje/1/)

I want this for input and can write only the following data types:

```
09/23/1980 or 09/23/80
```

for example if the user types the following format

`09231980` to turn in the following format 09/23/1980

How could I make such a function?
If you need further information, please tell me

**CODE HTML:**

```
<label>Date of birth<span class="star">*</span></label>
<input class="required-input valid" type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

**CODE JS:**

```
   $("date_of_birth").on('blur change', function () {
       text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$2/$2/$3");
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: what type of format you need... i m not geting u

Comment: And we can not do this custom?form scratch